# probability of quadratic polynomial

Tags: probability-theory, geometric-probability

How can we calculate the probability of quadratic polynomial such that

\begin{align}
\ Y=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2\\
\mathsf P\left(Y\lt y\right)=P
\end{align}

with y is such a number from this polynomial and is given

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean $P(a_0+a_1X+a_2X^2<y)$ where $X$ is a random variable of known distribution and $y$ a threshold value ?

Comment: yes of course, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

$$P(Y<y)=\int_{a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2<y}\text{pdf}(x)\,dx=\sum_k\left.\text{cdf}(x)\right|_{l_k}^{u_k}$$ where the sum is over the (zero, one or two, possibly infinte) intervals $l_k<x<u_k$ where the quadratic inequality holds.

Comment: @Djamel: why didn't you say it ?

Comment: @ Yves Daoust : because of that i wrote it as polynomial not as pdf function,

Comment: @Djamel: though you answered positively to my question with a "yes of course".

Comment: actually I want to estimate this without using the pdf, I tried before to use the logistic regression (0 and 1 output) , but i want to estimate it directly from the quadratic polynomial,

Comment: Yves Daoust :  thanks

Comment: @ Yves Daoust : it is very helpful

Comment: @ Yves Daoust imagine that we have X is a matrix that means (multiples inputs), How can we calculate the  cdf(x) ?